# How do I redirect all URLs containing a specific directory to a lowercase version of the directory? eg /Test/ to /test/

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

How do I correctly 301 redirect in htaccess the following, I'm specifically concerned with how it handles the case of the directory name. I've searched this website, for "301 redirect specific directory to lowercase", but couldn't find what I needed.

`/Test/any-file-name.html`
to
`/test/any-file-name.html`

AND

`/Test/`
to
`/test/`

with or without a trailing slash.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use this rule in your site root .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^Test/(.*)$ /test/$1 [L,R=301,NE]
```